# Adjust jquery filtering script to run on page reload based on checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a filtering script and I need some help.

My question is, how can I check what filters are selected (they remain checked on page reload/going back from a different page) and run the filtering script on page reload?

The page is: https://www.raw-partner.de/wer-wir-sind/team-2/

The user interaction is loading the page - clicking on 'Filter' - selecting the checkboxes/filters user desired - clicking on an entry which redirects to a different page - when going back the same filters must be applied. (note: the previously checked checkboxes remain checked once going back, so the only thing to do is to run the script again)

I can post the script as well.

Any idea on how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<ul class="filters box">
    <li>
        <input name="is-partner" type="checkbox" value="partner" id="partner" />
        <label for="partner">Partner</label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="other-job" type="checkbox" value="berufstrager" id="berufstrager" />
        <label for="berufstrager"> Berufsträger </label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="other-job" type="checkbox" value="mitarbeiter" id="mitarbeiter" />
        <label for="mitarbeiter"> Mitarbeiter </label>
    </li>

</ul>

<ul class="filters box">
<li style="font-weight: bold"> Standorte </li>
<li>
        <input name="location" type="checkbox" value="munchen" id="munchen" />
        <label for="munchen"> München </label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="location" type="checkbox" value="berlin" id="berlin" />
        <label for="berlin">Berlin</label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="location" type="checkbox" value="bad-worishofen" id="bad-worishofen" />
        <label for="bad-worishofen">Bad Wörishofen</label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="location" type="checkbox" value="gera" id="gera" />
        <label for="gera">Gera</label>
    </li>
</ul>


<ul class="filters box">
<li style="font-weight: bold"> Partner mit Team </li>
<li>
        <input name="parner-team" type="checkbox" value="appelt-duile" id="appelt-duile" />
        <label for="appelt-duile"> Appelt/Duile </label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="parner-team" type="checkbox" value="bley" id="bley" />
        <label for="bley"> Bley </label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="parner-team" type="checkbox" value="dietrich-kogler" id="dietrich-kogler" />
        <label for="dietrich-kogler"> Dietrich/Kögler </label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="parner-team" type="checkbox" value="barth" id="barth" />
        <label for="barth"> Dr. Barth </label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="parner-team" type="checkbox" value="buck" id="buck" />
        <label for="buck"> Dr. Buck </label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="parner-team" type="checkbox" value="drost" id="drost" />
        <label for="drost"> Drost </label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="parner-team" type="checkbox" value="lux-kronig-harbauer" id="lux-kronig-harbauer" />
        <label for="lux-kronig-harbauer"> Lux-Krönig/Harbauer </label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="parner-team" type="checkbox" value="metzler" id="metzler" />
        <label for="metzler"> Metzler </label>
    </li>
<li>
        <input name="parner-team" type="checkbox" value="stegmann" id="stegmann" />
        <label for="stegmann"> Stegmann </label>
    </li>
</ul>


</div>

</div>

<div id="filtering">

<div class="entry" data-id="max-appelt" data-category="partner munchen berufstrager appelt-duile">
<a href="http://www.raw-partner.de/maximilian-appelt-4/" target="_blank"><p><img class="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Appelt_P_0613_Zuschnitt.png" alt="null" /></p>
<h3 id="name"><b>Maximilian <br> Appelt</b></h3></a>
</div>

<div class="entry" data-category="partner munchen berufstrager barth">
<a href="http://www.raw-partner.de/dr-hans-guenther-barth/" target="_blank"><p><img class="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Barth_P_0187_Zuschnitt.png" alt="null" /></p>
<h3 id="name"><b>Dr. Hans Günther Barth</b></h3></a>
</div>

<div class="entry" data-category="munchen mitarbeiter ">

<a href="http://www.raw-partner.de/katrin-bartl-3/" target="_blank"><p><img class="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Bartl_0820_F_Zuschnitt.png" alt="null" /></p>
<h3 id="name"><b>Katrin <br> Bartl</b></h3></a>

</div>

<div class="entry" data-id="hans" data-category="bad-worishofen mitarbeiter stegmann">

<a href="http://www.raw-partner.de/alexander-baumgaertner-2/"><p><img class="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Baumgärtner_0035_F2.png" alt="null" /></p>
<h3 id="name"><b>Alexander <br> Baumgärtner</b></h3></a>

</div>

<div class="entry" data-id="hans" data-category="bad-worishofen mitarbeiter">

<a href="http://www.raw-partner.de/margit-baur-3/"><p><img class="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Baur_0533_F_Zuschnitt.png" alt="null" /></p>
<h3 id="name"><b>Margit <br> Baur</b></h3></a>

</div>

<div class="entry" data-id="hans" data-category="bad-worishofen mitarbeiter">

<a href="http://www.raw-partner.de/peter-harbauer-3-7/"><p><img class="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Bernhardt_0137_Zuschnitt.png" alt="null" /></p>
<h3 id="name"><b>Yvonne <br> Bernhardt</b></h3></a>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
(function($){ 
    var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

    $filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {

      var selectedFilters = {};

      $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {

        if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
          selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
        }

        selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);

      });

      var $filteredResults = $('.entry');

      $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

        $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

          var matched = false,
            currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

          $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {

            if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
              matched = true;
              return false;
            }
          });

          return matched;

        });
      });

      $('.entry').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();

    });

    $(window).trigger('resize')
      })(jQuery);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u39kmoxz/2/

Note: I have a basic understanding of jQuery, not advanced enough to use cookies, I was thinking that since the checkboxes are remaining checked when going back, the only thing that should be done is re-running the script but I can't understand how since the script is being applied on change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

Conceptually, you need to make the function callable from 2 events: change checkbox + page load. Therefore you need to *name* the function so that you can call it from these 2 events.

```
(function($){ 
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

var doFiltering =  function() {

  var selectedFilters = {};

  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {

    if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
      selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
    }

    selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);

  });

  var $filteredResults = $('.entry');

  $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

    $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {

      var matched = false,
        currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');

      $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {

        if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
          matched = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      return matched;

    });
  });

  $('.entry').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();

} // end of doFiltering function

$filterCheckboxes.on('change',doFiltering()); // call it with the on change
doFiltering() // call it when your parent function executes at page load (only executes once)

$(window).trigger('resize')
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer! This is a good approach that didn't cross my mind. The only problem is that the filtering doesn't work anymore, changed the current script with this one and the filtering is not triggered anymore when checking checkboxes.

Comment: Managed to make it work by replacing $filterCheckboxes.on('change', doFiltering()); with $filterCheckboxes.change(doFiltering);